# How do you run `bin/rails test` without triggering yarn compilation every time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

If I run tests with `bin/rails test` it triggers yarn to run twice, once for esbuild and once for css. If I run all the same tests with `bin/rails test test/**/**.rb` or `bin/rails test test/` the tests run instantly.

Why is this happening when I'm not running System Tests)?

**Versions:** Rails 7.1.1, Ruby 3.2.2, Minitest 5.20.0
App created with `rails new my_app --javascript esbuild --css bootstrap`

---

#### Additional question - How do I figure this out for myself next time?

My test helper doesn't seem to be calling `rails test:prepare` or anything else that triggers yarn:

```rb
# test/test_helper.rb
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"

module ActiveSupport
  class TestCase
    # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
    parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

    # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
    fixtures :all

    # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  end
end
```

I've tried to go through each `require`d file in `test_helper.rb` and can't find anywhere else that yarn/assets/precompilation is being told to happen:

- `../config/environment` ❌

  - `config/application` ❌

    - `config/boot` ❌
    - `rails/all` ❓ (didn't even know where to begin)
- `rails/test_help` ❓ (read through [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/railties/lib/rails/test_help.rb) but only looked in to one of the things it requires)

  - `active_support/testing/autorun` ❌ ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/autorun.rb))

I also tried `bundle open minitest` on the off chance something is configured there but I poked around a bit and couldn't see anything relevant.

Where is the yarn/asset-compilation "magic" configured for tests?

Comment: "How do I figure this out for myself next time?" - `require "debug"; debugger` and then `next` or `step` to see what is going on. https://github.com/ruby/debug

Comment: Any suggestions where I should add the call to `debugger`? Even if it's at the top of `test_helper.rb` it doesn't get triggered until after the `test:prepare` step

Comment: yes that would be too late. inside `bin/rails` would be the place, and then quite a bit of stepping, because it's an awkward place to start. (note, it's bad form to change your original question after you got an answer, just ask another one)

Comment: I was trying to make the title match the question in the body but you're right, changed back (and updated body of post to match the title)

Comment: @Matthew I believe you have already self answered the previous question of how to avoid this, which is to pass a path to `rails test` e.g. `bin/rails test test/`. As you can see by the source code passing a path skips `run_prepare_task`

Comment: Yes but it's not possible to run the "normal" suite that way (avoiding system tests). I thought `bin/rails test test/ --exclude test/system` would solve it but that doesn't work. The best I've come up with is to list all the folders containing tests (other than system): `bin/rails test test/{channels,controllers,integration,mailers,models}/`. Thanks again for the link to the code @engineersmnky ... that led me to the PR implementing the change where I've been following this up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "My test helper doesn't seem to be calling `rails test:prepare`"

When you call `rails test` without any arguments it calls `test:prepare` for you [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands/test/test_command.rb#L32)

```
run_prepare_task if self.args.none?(EXACT_TEST_ARGUMENT_PATTERN)
```

and [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-1-stable/railties/lib/rails/commands/test/test_command.rb#L72)

```
Rails::Command::RakeCommand.perform("test:prepare", [], {})
```

As Noted in the [Upgrade Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#bin-rails-test-now-runs-test-prepare-task)

> When running tests via `bin/rails test`, the `rake test:prepare` task will run before tests run. If you've enhanced the `test:prepare` task, your enhancements will run before your tests. `tailwindcss-rails`, `jsbundling-rails`, and `cssbundling-rails` enhance this task, as do other third party gems.

You can see that this indeed builds `yarn`  [Cssbundling](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails/blob/main/lib/tasks/cssbundling/build.rake#L48) and [Jsbundling](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/blob/main/lib/tasks/jsbundling/build.rake#L49)

Comment: There's a discussion of why this change was introduced at https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/46664